# SVM regression ruined by adding polynomial features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I'm trying to get the feel for SVM regression with a toy example. I generated random numbers between 1 and 100 as the predictors, then took their log and added gaussian noise to create the target variables. Popping this data into sklearn's SVR module produces a reasonable looking model:

[image]

However, when I augment the training data by throwing in the squares of the original predictor variables, everything goes haywire:

[image]

I understand that the RBF kernel does something analogous to taking powers of the original features, so throwing in the second feature is mostly redundant. However, is it really the case the SVMs are this bad at handling feature redundancy? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code I used to generate these graphs:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# change to highest_power=2 to get the bad model
def create_design_matrix(x_array, highest_power=1):
    return np.array([[x**k for k in range(1, highest_power + 1)] for x in x_array])

N = 1000

x_array = np.random.uniform(1, 100, N) 
y_array = np.log(x_array) + np.random.normal(0,0.2,N)

model = SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.1)
print model

X = create_design_matrix(x_array)
#print X
#print y_array

model = model.fit(X, y_array)


test_x = np.linspace(1.0, 100.0, num=10000)
test_y = model.predict(create_design_matrix(test_x))
plt.plot(x_array, y_array, 'ro')
plt.plot(test_x, test_y)
plt.show()
```

I'd appreciate any help with this mystery!

Comment: Did you mess around with C at all?

Comment: Yep, I tried values from 0.01 to 1000 for C (and played with epsilon a bit as well) but couldn't get a reasonable curve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model's picking up on outliers too heavily, which is a symptom of error from variance. This makes sense, because adding polynomial features increases the variance of a model. You should try tweaking the bias-variance tradeoff via cross validation by tweaking parameters. The parameters to modify would be C, epsilon, and gamma. The gamma parameter's incredibly important when using an RBF kernel, so I'd start there.

Manually fiddling with these parameters (which is not recommended - see below) gave me the following model:

[image]

The parameters used here were C=5, epsilon=0.1, gamma=2**-15.

Choosing these parameters is really a task for a proper model selection framework. I prefer simulated annealing + cross validation. The best scikit-learn currently has is random grid search +  crossval. Shameless plug for a simulated annealing module I helped with: https://github.com/skylergrammer/SimulatedAnnealing

Note: Polynomial features are actually products of all combinations of size d (with replacement), not just the squares of features. In the second degree case, since you only have a single feature, these are equivalent. Scikit-learn has a class that'll calculate these though: sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures